# Solving difference equation using linear algebra

Tags: recurrence-relations, signal-processing

Suppose we wish to solve a differnece equation  by using linear algebra, just like presented in Strang's Linear Algebra book.

Now let's say we have the difference equation: $h[n]+\frac{2}{3}h[n-1] +\frac{1}{9}h[n-2] = 0$.

Using the method we have the system: $\begin{bmatrix} h[n] \\ h[n-1]\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} -2/3 
&-1/9 \\ 1 & 0\end{bmatrix} \cdot \begin{bmatrix} h[n-1] \\ h[n-2]\end{bmatrix}$. where we are given that h[0]=1, $h[1]=-\frac{2}{3}$.

The above system can be written as $ u_k = A u_{k-1}$ and solving recursively we have $u_k = A^{k-1}u_1.$

We can write $A^{k-1}$ as : $A^{k-1} = S\cdot Λ ^{k-1}\cdot S^{-1}$ where S is the matrix containing the eigenvectors of A and Λ is the matrix containing the eigenvalues of A, raised to the power k-1.

The problem is that S is not ivertible as there is a repeated eigenvector. In that case ,the above form of $A^{k-1}$ is not valid.

However there is still a solution to the above difference equation.

My question is how do we get a solution
of difference equations where the eigenvalue is repeated as in this case?

Any source that contains a derivation to the solution of the above difference equation is preffered. Thanks.

Comment: $S$ is a matrix with columns consisting of an eigenvector and a generalized eigenvector, $\Lambda$ is of the form $$\pmatrix{\lambda&1\cr0&\lambda\cr}$$ and there still a simple form for $\Lambda^n$.

Comment: Thanks. As I have written above I know that already :) My question is how do we solve this difference equation.

Comment: And that's what I've told you. I've told you what happens when you have a repeated eigenvalue. You need an eigenvector **and a generalized eigenvector**. You don't get a diagonal matrix $\Lambda$, **you get a Jordan block, as indicated**. You **did not** know that already, or at least nothing you wrote indicated that you knew that already – if you knew that, you'd know how to solve the difference equation with the repeated eigenvalue. The only thing I've left out is exactly how to get the generalized eigenvector, and what exactly $\Lambda^n$ looks like when $\Lambda$ isn't diagonal.

Comment: (continued) But I think I'll let you work those out on your own.

Comment: So, making progress?

Comment: Hey. Sorry for my first response.. I didn't exactly understand what you wrote. Also I only now got some time to look at these. Will this help me solve these kind of difference equations? Like the one in the example above? Thanks.

Comment: If you work through what I've written, and understand it, then it will tell you exactly how to solve this kind of difference equation. Well, it will tell you one way to solve these; there are other ways that don't involve matrices.

Comment: Hey, I managed to work this out exactly as you explained.  Thanks for your answer!

Comment: Good. Let me encourage you to write up your solution and post it as an answer.